# Drawing an NSTableView's background outside of its bounds

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, nstableview, nsscrollview

I'm having a problem since Lion introduced elastic scrolling (pictured below). When you scroll my table view (cell-based, with alternating row colors) beyond its bounds, the background doesn't draw. I've tried doing my own drawing in `-[drawBackgroundInClipRect:]`, but it seems like you can't exceed the bounds of the table view. How can I extend the background into elastic scrolling territory?

[image: Scrolling left of table]

Comment: It's the containing NSScrollView that is doing the drawing in this area. Perhaps you can create a pattern for the alternating rows and set that as the background color in the scroll view?

Comment: Is this still an issue? I'm unable to reproduce this effect in OS X 10.9.

Comment: @jemmons Not sure I will update once I'm on Mavericks.

Comment: If you by chance not planning to use alternating rows and still want to support lion then use cell spacing height to adjust and present a clear distinction between the rows, adjusting these setting will make it look clean and neat.

Answer (score 0):

**In Answer to Your Question**

A view drawing outside its bounds is generally a no-no. When using alternating background colors, the NSTableView draws its background directly. But in a view-based table view, NSTableRowView is used and if it has its own background color, this is poses even more challenge.

**The Bad News**

The assemblage of NSScrollView (and its various parts), NSTableView, and NSTableHeaderView is complicated on its own. Once you throw view-based functionality into the mix (where each row has a view and each cell has their own view, and each are reused, animated around, etc.), overriding this behavior "is no way to go through life, son!" ;-)

**The Good News**

The issue of alternating background colors not extending in an elastically-stretched scrolled table view *has* been resolved (at least on 10.10, that I can tell), so this is no longer an issue unless you have row/cell views with custom backgrounds or just background colors.

**A General Solution For Custom Document (Scrolled) Views**

For all other scrolled views with ruled backgrounds you wish to extend for elastic scrolling, you'll need a custom NSScrollView subclass that expects a document view (your custom scrolled view) to conform to a protocol you define (like `-(NSImage *)backgroundImageForClipViewBounds:`). The scroll view would observe its content view (NSClipView) for **bounds** change notifications and flag itself for display. When the scroll view's `-drawRect:` is called, it would then ask the scrolled view for its `-backgroundImageForClipViewBounds:` (via your protocol) and draw it into itself, thereby making the scrolled view's "infinite background" its own.

I haven't tested this theory but I believe it would work. I hope this helps.